# Visual Studio intellisense and debug only in certain areas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I wrote a simple web-server that interprets c# inside HTML in real time (Like Razor, but it looks more like PHP style tags, just written in C#). Every C# code snippet is wrapped with `<@` and `@>`.

Now, I want to start writing a simple web application using it. Working with Notepad++ is painfully annoying, due to the fact it cannot really autocomplete C# well, and C# is a strict language (unlike PHP, Javascript or Python, in which developing in Atom or NP++ is extremely easy and natural).

So, the question:
I wanted to know if there is any way that I can edit those pages in Visual Studio, have all the autocomplete functionality, and in the same time let VS know that I want it to notice (colorize, syntax-check, etc) only code snippets wrapped in `<@` and `@>`.

How do I do that?

- Visual studio 2015
- Can be **web developer** or **desktop version**, I can any of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a very powerful extension SDK, so you can achieve what you want by developing one or more extensions. If you're new to extension development, I'd suggest you take a look at [this getting started guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166030.aspx) first.

Microsoft has quite a few samples available on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples). At least the following two samples should be of interest to you.

Syntax coloring: [Diff Classifier Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Diff_Classifier)

Custom programming language support: [Ook Language Integration Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Ook_Language_Integration)

The Ook sample goes a bit further than what you actually need, but it has some elements that are usable to you.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a good direction. Even though the problem isn't solved until I really make that extension, for now I'll mark the answer as correct :)
If I have any questions, I'll comment here.

Comment: Good luck and have fun with the development. Developing extensions opens up a whole new world of possibilities!